# Retrieve data from Excel in WinForms

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel which contains data. I would like to read the data from column A's cell value to column F's cell value and continue to read next x columns's cell value where x equals the cell value read at column F. For example:

```
         A B C D E F G H I J
         a a a a a 1 a a a a
```

F's cell value is 1 so i would like to read ( G H I J)
If F's cell value is 2 the i would like to read ( G H I J K L M N)

```
         A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
         a a a a a 2 a a a a a a a a
```

F's cell value 3 :

```
        A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
        a a a a a 3 a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- [.NET Interop](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)
- [Directly parsing the OpenXML document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (Office 2007 and greater)

The first is much easier, but the second works when you don't have Excel installed.

Comment: I'm already using Interop but i don't know how to do it ... The question is : how can i implement it ?

Comment: I have a code , but it does not work ... i was just hoping to see how would someone else resolve it ..

Answer (score 0):

```
// OPEN EXCEL and WORKSHEET   

 xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\TEST.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
 xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

// F column index starting, A == 1
int lastColumnIndex = 6; 

// read each cell including 'F1' and add it to the richTextBox (it is my placeholder in test project)
for (int i = 1; i <= lastColumnIndex; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToString(((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i]).Value2));
}

// read and save the value of 'F1' to a variable - 2nd read of the same cell can be avoided, though
int extraColumnsToRead = Convert.ToInt32(((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, lastColumnIndex]).Value2) * 4;

// (value(F1) * 4) cells will be loaded and added to my RichTextBox.
if (extraColumnsToRead > 0)
    for (int i = lastColumnIndex + 1; i <= lastColumnIndex + extraColumnsToRead; i++)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToString(((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i]).Value2));
    }
```